# outer curved layer for navbar in css

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to make outer curved layer for navbar in CSS but I don't know how to do it.

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  top: 15%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1;
  width: 200;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 182px;
  color: #64686d;
}

.current {
  color: white;
  background-color: #21252a;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: #292d32;
  padding: 1em;
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #292d32;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="dashboard.html" class="current">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="Calendar.html" class="calendar">Calendar</a></li>
  <li><a href="Graphs.html" class="graphs">Graphs</a></li>
  <li><a href="Add.html" class="add">Add</a></li>
  <li><a href="Settings.html" class="settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read _[How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ and _[How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe  you need here pseudo-elements coupled with shadows to create a nice illusion. To understand how it works I would recommend checking out this tutorial: https://itnext.io/how-to-make-a-fancy-inverted-border-radius-in-css-5db048a53f95

```css
ul{
position: relative;
left: 0%;
top: 15%;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 1;
width: 200;

}

li a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 45px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 182px;
    color: #64686d;
}
.current{
    color: white;
    background-color: #21252a;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.current::before, .current::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;  
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
}

.current::before{
  bottom: -40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 -25px 0 0 #21252a;
}
.current::after{
  top: -40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 25px 0 0 #21252a;
}


.wrapper > div{
    background: #292d32;
    padding: 1em;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(odd){
    background: #292d32;
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li><a href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="Calendar.html" class="calendar current">Calendar</a></li>
      <li><a href="Graphs.html" class="graphs">Graphs</a></li>
      <li><a href="Add.html" class="add">Add</a></li>
      <li><a href="Settings.html" class="settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use :before or :after for that, and then you can use css for make the shape that you want or you can use any images as background of pseudo element.

```
.item{
background:#000;
width:300px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
}
.item:before{
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
background:#fff;
width:100%;
height:20px;
border-radius:30px;
}
```